# iOS Memory leak on Google Ad / AVFAudio

Tags: ios, admob, adsense, avaudiosession

I have noticed that every time I call a `UIViewcontroller` that has *Google Ad banner* and when I dismiss it, the memory is not able to be deallocated.

So, when I checked it on Instruments It gave me this error:
`Memory Leak when running: [_adBannerView loadRequest:request]. Responsible Library: AVFAudio`

Even after posting on Google forum [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/TOYV8PNKktM), they said that this error is not from their SDK or not caused by their SDK, that's from native iOS call with `AVAudioSession`

Any solution for this?

Comment: Looking at your code on Google forum, aren't you creating a circular reference loop by `_adBannerView.rootViewController = self`? Shouldn't that be a `weak self`? Might be that AVAudioSession is a side effect of the _adBannerView object itself being leaked.

Comment: @dirkgroten `rootViewController = self` doesn't create retain cycle. After `dismiss` being called, its memory might be released. Like `dataSource = self` or `delegate = self`

Comment: You're right, I didn't see it's declared as `weak` in GoogleMobileAds SDK.

Comment: @dirkgroten Actually, i saw they already put `weak` on their code `@property(nonatomic, weak, GAD_NULLABLE) IBOutlet UIViewController *rootViewController;`. They said the trouble caused by `AVAudioSession`, eventually there's no clue to workaround or fix it